# How to swap WordPress and Shop locations

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog setup in the root directory and an ecommerce shop in a sub-directory like:

```
    http://example.com             //the blog is here
    http://example.com/ecommerce/  //this is the shop
```

I want to swap those so that it is

```
    http://example.com          //this is the shop  
    http://example.com/blog/    //the blog is here
```

I know how to move the files and make all of the database changes so both the blog and shop will work. The problem is with the redirection. How do I redirect the links that used to go to the blog to the new location without causing all of the shop urls to redirect too?

That is, I can add redirect code from the ecommerce directory to the root and that would take care of the shop's links. But if I then redirect from the root to the blog directory to get the blog to work, the shop links will fail.

Is there a way to do this?

To clarify this a little, here are what some of the links to the blog are:

```
    http://example.com/
    http://example.com/contact-us/
    http://example.com/category/culture/
```

Abd here are some to the shop:

```
    http://example.com/ecommerce/
    http://example.com/ecommerce/contact_us.php
    http://example.com/ecommerce/baby-power-id=558
```

Answer (score 0):

The only really robust way is really to list them all individually or by pattern. But perhaps it can be achieved by redirecting anything where the file doesn't exist, but does exist in the new location. Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /blog/$1 [R,L=301]
```

It assumes:

- all your old blog URLs do not contain any forward slashes
- that the URLs, without the query string being examined, are different from the shop ones
- that no other URL rewriting is being used

Otherwise let me know.

Comment: There will be blog url's with slashes and there will be other url rewriting. I could probably do the blog url rewriting by individual entries since there shouldn't be too many but the shop will have many product url/s to change. But if niether of those were problems, I would still want to redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com for SEO. And since the latter would also be redirected to the blog, it seems that only one or the other will work.  Seems like there's no way around this unless I just ignore the affect it will have with the search engines.

Comment: Well the shop is easy. You can just redirect anything under the /ecommerce/ directory. The problem with the blog is that it's in root. So it's more tricky. Do you want code for redirecting the old shop? No need to ignore one or the other of those requirements you mention, you can do both of them, rules can be done to cover it. Update your answer with more info - what your old blog URLs can be, your current rules, your requirement to add www - and I'll make some suggestions for you, as perhaps will others.

Comment: You mention the latter being redirected to the blog. So are you saying `www.example.com/` should redirect to `www.example.com/blog/`? Isn't `www.example.com/` the new shop homepage? Remember each unique URL can only do one thing. It can't be the shop homepage and also redirect to the new blog homepage. Writing out your full requirements in the question will help clarify everything I'm sure.

Comment: I have updated my question with example links. I know how to redirect from the ecommerce directory to the root but as mentioned, the url can only be for one thing. It seems to be a catch-22 situation.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll add another answer with some thoughts on this. For the homepage, yes, it can't do both. You'll have to decide what you want it to do. I suggest not having it redirect and having a link to the blog index from it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the redirects but they don't really address the main problem, which I may still not have explained well enough. Right now, if someone visits example.com, the blog is displayed. After I make this change, that url will display the shop, which would then be in the root. So any links to example.com will then be incorrect. Maybe I should I just ignore that particular situation since it will only be the one url? It is just that the blog currently ranks well and I would prefer not losing that, if possible. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the old blog URLs individually or by pattern, you can do the following.

**Complete Blog Directories**

For each complete directory, do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(category/.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Use one for each directory, change 'category' to be the name of the directory for each and it will be redirected to the same under '/blog/'. Obviously the shop can't be using the same directory names.

**Separate Blog URLs**

For each other URL, have a rule:

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ /blog/contact-us/
```

That should work well for moving the blog URLs without affecting the shop.

**Shop**

For the shop, just use:

```
RewriteRule ^ecommerce/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```